# Android Studio, Visual Studio installation freezing issue.

Tags: windows, visual-studio, android-studio, download, installation

Whenever I am installing program every thing is frozen. I can't exit programs or open anything. Cant even right click on anything. 
The only thing I can do is moving the installing setup window around and watch the bar be stuck at 84%.
I can't even open windows menu, ctrl + alt + delete doesn't work.

It's a  new computer With 
    8gb ram
    Intel i5
    250gb SSD

I only use the computer to programming and work nothing else
Any tips?

Comment: Tips? Take your brand new laptop/computer to service. _"This isnt a programming issue"_ yes we are programming enthusiasts not hardware specialists.

Comment: What’s your OS version and VS version? Before installation, please make sure windows update is up-to-date, temporarily disable any antivirus software, clean up %temp% folder and re-run VS installer as administrator. If this issue persists, please use http://aka.ms/vscollect to gather the installation logs. After using it, you will find vslogs.zip under %temp% folder, then upload the file to https://onedrive.live.com/ and share the link here.